# Asp.net weird config or setup issue

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a weird asp.net webforms website issue. Its developed in vs2008 with forms authentication and mysql backend.  Its working fine on dev system (win7) and in may production servers.

On new 2008 R2 server its behavior is odd. When I login through login page it redirects properly to default page, but user menu is not generated. But if I recycle app pool and refresh the page, menu appears and works fine afterwords. And if a logout and login, again same problem occurs, No menu until app pool recycle.

From log, It looks like its not getting values from DB. Even though data is there. It shows proper user name for httpcontext and shows user is authenticated. And no error is shown in log, event log etc.

Not sure whats happening here.

**UPDATE :**

I'm using log4net and loging info to log. Something could be wrong in code.

Here part of web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="tmsConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=54545;persist security info=false;database=tms;port=3306;convert zero datetime=yes;Allow Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="archiveConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=55645;database=archive;persist security info=True;port=3306;convert zero datetime=yes;Allow Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="tmsConnectionString" applicationName="tms" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="Andri.Web.MySqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="Andri.Web.MySqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="tmsConnectionString" applicationName="tms" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" slidingExpiration="false" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" path="/" protection="All" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="180" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Here is page load of default page.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            log.Debug("User - " + Page.User.Identity.Name);
            log.Debug("User IsAuthenticated- " + Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
            log.Debug("User AuthenticatedType- " + Page.User.Identity.AuthenticationType);

            if (Page.User.IsInRole(Tms.Constants.Roles.Administrator))
            {
                log.Debug("role: Administrator");
                ASPxMenu1.Items[0].Visible = true;
            }
            else if (Page.User.IsInRole(Tms.Constants.Roles.Manager))
            {
                log.Debug("role: Manager");
                ASPxMenu1.Items[1].Visible = true;
            }
            else {
                log.Debug("Menu not created - Role not supported");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is code to check if user in role, using membership role manager

```
    public static bool IsInRole(this IPrincipal User, Tms.Constants.Roles roletype)
    {
        string role = roletype.ToString().ToLower();
        log.DebugFormat("IsInRole role: {0}", role.ToLower());
        log.DebugFormat("IsInRole user: {0}", User.Identity.Name);

        return User.IsInRole(role.ToLower());
    }
```

Here is the log

```
INFO  2012-06-17  LoginPage              Login1_LoggedIn    - Logged In: admin
DEBUG 2012-06-17  DefaultPage            Page_Load          - User - admin
DEBUG 2012-06-17  DefaultPage            Page_Load          - User IsAuthenticated- True
DEBUG 2012-06-17  DefaultPage            Page_Load          - User AuthenticatedType- Forms
INFO  2012-06-17  User                   IsInRole           - IsInRole role: administrator
INFO  2012-06-17  User                   IsInRole           - IsInRole user: admin
INFO  2012-06-17  User                   IsInRole           - IsInRole role: manager
INFO  2012-06-17  User                   IsInRole           - IsInRole user: admin
DEBUG 2012-06-17  DefaultPage            Page_Load          - Menu not created - Role not supported
```

If I login as user "Admin", it goes to Menu not created. Even though "Admin" is in role administrator.

Weird thing is, Instead of membership providers "User.IsInRole", If I use custom logic to get user info, DB is still not returning any values. Ex:

```
    static public int GetUserId(string name)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("UserIdFromUsername({0})", name);

        using (var TA = new Tms.DataAccessTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter())
        {
            log.DebugFormat("connection({0})", TA.Connection.ConnectionString);

            var usertable = TA.GetDataBy_Username(name);

            log.DebugFormat("count({0})", usertable.Rows.Count.ToString());
            if (usertable.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                return usertable[0].Id;
            }
            else { return 0; }
        }
    }
```

Log of it

```
DEBUG 2012-06-17  User                   GetUserId          - UserIdFromUsername(admin)
DEBUG 2012-06-17  User                   GetUserId          - connection(server=localhost;user id=root;password=54545;persist security info=false;database=tms;port=3306;convert zero datetime=yes;Allow Zero Datetime=True)
DEBUG 2012-06-17  User                   GetUserId          - count(0)
```

So its not returning user info, even though that user exists in DB.

If I recycle IIS app pool and just refresh page everything start working for both cases, I mean membership provider or custom logic. That's until I log out. Login again, same problem.

There is error logging at app level, but no error. No error or message in system event log related to this from IIS related services.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in your code rather than a config issue (of course your code might be making assumptions about configuration which causes problems). I suggest you use a logging framework (such as log4net or roll your own simple FileStream-based logger) and write details about the program state to the logger at key points during page/controller execution then inspect them later - it's the closest you'll get to remote debugging you can get.

The best solution is to install the VS remote debugging tools and connect to the server where you're having the problems, but this might be a problem if you've got a inter-domain trust and authentication issues to deal with (DCOM is a major part of MDM and Remote Debugging and can cause problems that take ages to sort out, just a warning).

UPDATE:

Thanks for posting the log. I see you're doing .ToLower() when writing to your log. I wonder if a case-sensitivity issue is causing the IsInRole function to behave undesirably. Remember SQL string comparison is case-insensitive, but C#'s is case-sensitive.